# Hi people, unable to find ORACLE_HOME/bin in registry editor > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software/ oracle > KEY_OraDB19Home1, installing oracle 19c

Tags: windows, oracle, installation, plsql, oracle19c

unable to find ORACLE_HOME/bin in registry editor > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/software/ oracle > KEY_OraDB19Home1, installing oracle 19c.

please help for the same, so that I can finish my installation.

[image]

Comment: Apart from the fact that you can't find that key, what actual **problem** are you trying to solve? I mean, why do you think that it is important that you find it in registry?

Comment: I am installing oracle 19c in my system,  after database registration successfully. next step is to- go to command prompt, and run command :./dbca from the $ORACLE_HOME/bin

Comment: Can you search for dbca.bat under d:\? Or can you just run `dbca` without the path prefix (in case the location is already added to your path) and if it starts, make sure it's the expected version? I'm not sure what the significance of the `:./` prefix is.

Comment: Also, there won't be a separate registry entry for ORACLE_HOME/bin. There should be an entry for ORACLE_HOME, and the bin folder is implicitly located there.